# Script to search a column for a value and return the row number to use in a variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code I use to send email reminders based on dates in a spreadsheet.  Most of the sheets I use it for are simple and under 100 lines of data.  In the past I have used individual variables for each cell but I am looking for a way to find all instances of a value in a column (D), in this case, it is a city code ("SEA"), and return the row number, which I then want to take and use in a var to make it act like a vlookup.

`ex: var empname = ss.getRange("A"+ rownumber).getValue();`

Which should return column A of whichever row has "SEA" in it.

The challenge then is to be able to go down the column and do the same for each row that has "SEA" in it.

This is a one-line version of what I have done in the past.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Active");

var empnum = ss.getRange("A8").getValue();

var empfirstname = ss.getRange("C8").getValue();

var emplastname = ss.getRange("B8").getValue();

var emplocation = ss.getRange("D8").getValue();

var test = ss.getRange("H8").getValue();


   if (test === -1 && emplocation === "SEA"){
      var message =  empnum + " " + empfirstname + ' ' + emplastname + ' is past due for testing.' + '\n'
      } else if (test === 0 && emplocation === "SEA"){
        var message = empnum + " " + empfirstname + ' ' + emplastname + ' will be due for testing soon.' + '\n'
        } else if (test === 1) {
          var message = "";
          }



  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email Group").getRange("A1");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();



  var subject = 'Test reminder';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,  '**This is an automated message**\n\n' + 'Test reminder:\n\n' + message + '\n\n**This is an automated message**\n');
    }
```

The H column will present a -1, 0 or 1 depending on the date in the G column to determine if someone is due to take a test or not.  I then want to send an email with the Employee Number, First Name and Last Name for each employee at the SEA branch.  This has worked for me in the past but I have 230+ lines of employees and don't want to create that many variables.  My solution is to get the row number of each row with a "SEA" location and use that as a variable in a getRange call.  Not sure exactly how that would work, or if it even would.  If there is a better solution, I am amenable to that.

Comment: Do you want this to send one email per row that meets your criteria?

Comment: Negative, I want one email with each row meeting the criteria as a separate line so it shows as a list of employees who are due for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Requirement:

Send an email when a row contains "SEA" and column H matches `-1` or `0`.

---

#### Solution:

```
function findAndSendMail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Active');

  //find all occurrences of "SEA" and push range to array
  var search = "SEA";      
  var ranges = ss.createTextFinder(search).findAll();      
  var message = ''; //pre-define email body

  //loop through each range
  for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {

    var row = ranges[i].getRow();
    var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
    var values = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastCol).getValues(); //get all values for the row
    var empnum = values[0][0];       //column A
    var empfirstname = values[0][2]; //column C
    var emplastname = values[0][1];  //column B
    var emplocation = values[0][3];  //column D
    var test = values[0][7];         //column H

    if (test === -1) {
      message+=Utilities.formatString(empnum + " " + empfirstname + ' ' + emplastname + ' is past due for testing.\n');
    } else if (test === 0) {
      message+=Utilities.formatString(empnum + " " + empfirstname + ' ' + emplastname + ' will be due for testing soon.\n');
    }
  }
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email Group").getRange("A1");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

  var subject = 'Test reminder';
  if (message) { //make sure message is not blank
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,  '**This is an automated message**\n\n' + 'Test reminder:\n\n' + message + '\n\n**This is an automated message**\n');
  }
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

Okay, so I've made quite a few changes to your original script, if there's anything I've missed please let me know, I'm happy to explain it.

First of all, I've changed the script so that we're using `textFinder`, this is so that we can search through your sheet to find your desired pattern "SEA". This then pushes all of the ranges to an array that we are looping through in the `for` loop.

When looping through the ranges, we can grab all of the data in the row (e.g. `values[0][0]` is the data in column A). This is then pushed to `var message` to build the email body in the same format you specified in your question.

I've tried to keep the variable names alike to the ones in your original script to make it easier to understand which parts of the script are essentially the same as your original. Also there are comments throughout the script that should help you understand what it's doing at each point.

---

#### References:

1. [`textFinder` Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

---

#### Update:

To scan only a certain column, try the code below instead. I've defined `var range` separately so that we can use `textFinder` on that range rather than the whole sheet.

```
function findAndSendMail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Active');

  //define range to search
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange(1, 4, lastRow); //range for column D

  //find all occurrences of "SEA" in column D and push range to array
  var search = "SEA"
  var ranges = range.createTextFinder(search).findAll();
  var message = '';

  //loop through each range
  for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {

    var row = ranges[i].getRow();
    var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
    var values = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastCol).getValues(); //get all values for the row
    var empnum = values[0][0];       //column A
    var empfirstname = values[0][2]; //column C
    var emplastname = values[0][1];  //column B
    var emplocation = values[0][3];  //column D
    var test = values[0][7];         //column H

    if (test === -1) {
      message+=Utilities.formatString(empnum + " " + empfirstname + ' ' + emplastname + ' is past due for testing.\n');
    } else if (test === 0) {
      message+=Utilities.formatString(empnum + " " + empfirstname + ' ' + emplastname + ' will be due for testing soon.\n');
    }
  }
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email Group").getRange("A1");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

  var subject = 'Test reminder';

  if (message) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,  '**This is an automated message**\n\n' + 'Test reminder:\n\n' + message + '\n\n**This is an automated message**\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: YES!  It works flawlessly.  Thank you for your time.  I am still quite novice and defining that many variables is a pain!  I have to dissect this to make sure I understand everything.  Thank you again!

Comment: Do you know why it might duplicate an employee in the middle of the list?  I have 6 employees due but the third in the list duplicates in the email.

Comment: Lastly, I may be pushing my luck here, but is there a way to add an if operation to the email so it doesn't send unless there are actually people to report?  Something perhaps along the lines of:  if (message === false) {null} else if (message === true) {/send email}

Comment: Does "SEA" appear twice in the column by any chance? As for the message check, this is completely possible - I've edited the code to include this.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much for your assistance, Ross.

Comment: And yes, SEA does appear twice, his name is Sean.  I think that may be the cause.  Is there a way to use the textfinder in only the one column?

Comment: I tried this: var ranges = ss.getRange('D8:D').createTextFinder(search).findAll();  But it didn't work.  When I debug, it just freezes out and then says System Error: Spreadsheets.

Comment: Haha I just tried the same thing and had the same error message as yourself. I've updated the answer with a method of searching just column D with the `textFinder`.

Comment: Excellent!  That did it!  Thank you, again.  I am going to dissect this code so I can learn it and utilize it elsewhere, too.  You've really helped me out!